# Como para el audio al cambiar de fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragment

Tengo 3 fragments dentro de un viewpager y en cada fragment hay un imageView en el cual tiene el metodo Onclick y al presionarlo, reproduce un sonido con mediaPlayer, Eh logrado hacer que se reproduzca cuando hacen clic sobre la imagen pero el problema es que al cambiar de fragment en los tabs, el sonido se sigue reproduciendo y quisiera saber como hacer que se detenga cuando el fragment es cambiado...

El codigo del MainActivity del fragment es el siguiente

```
public class Main_Activity_fabula2 extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main__fabula2);
    Toolbar myToolbar= findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Pagina 1"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Pagina 2"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Pagina 3"));


    tabLayout.setTabGravity(tabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
    final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    PagerAdapterFabula2 adapter = new PagerAdapterFabula2(getSupportFragmentManager(),tabLayout.getTabCount());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));



    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            int position = tab.getPosition();
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
}
```

}

Codigo del PagerAdapter

```
public class PagerAdapterFabula2 extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
private int numberoftabs;
public PagerAdapterFabula2(FragmentManager fm, int numberoftabs) {

    super(fm);
    this.numberoftabs=numberoftabs;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position){
        case 0:
            return new pagina1fabula2Fragment();

        case 1:
            return new pagina2fabula2Fragment();
        case 2:
            return new Fragmentpagina3fabula2();
            default:
                return null;
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return numberoftabs;
}
```

}

Codigo del Fragment

```
public class pagina2fabula2Fragment extends Fragment {
private MediaPlayer mp;

public pagina2fabula2Fragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ImageView imageView1;
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pagina3fabula2, container, false);
    imageView1=view.findViewById(R.id.imageviewPagina2Fabula2);
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(),R.raw.fabula2pagina2);
    imageView1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mp.start();
        }
    });

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    stopAudio();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    stopAudio();
}

private void stopAudio(){
    if (mp!=null){
        mp.stop();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, revisa por favor [ask], modifica tu pregunta, agrega lo que has tratado por favor, saludos

Comment: Hola, gracias por la sugerencia, eh editado el post, podrias darle una revisada de nuevo? Gracias

Comment: Muchas gracias Walter , de esta forma la comunidad se puede dar cuenta del problema que presentas o de lo que en realidad deseas, y te ayudaran de una mejor forma. gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Para detenerlo, cuando pasas por `onPause()` o `onDestroy()` deberias hacer un `stop()` del audio

```
fun stopAudio(){
 if(mediaPlayer != null ){
            mediaPlayer?.stop()
        }
}

 override fun onPause() {
        super.onDestroy()
       stopAudio()
    }


    override fun onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy()
            stopAudio()
        }
```

Comment: Hola, te refieres al ciclo de vida dentro del fragment verdad?? intentare hacerlo con codigo java, por lo visto es kotlin el ejemplo pero igual y me sirve... gracias

Comment: si, dentro del fragment

Comment: Lo eh implementado pero no me funciona, solo funciona en el metodo OnStop() y lo que hace es que se detiene si me salgo del mainActivity que contiene los fragments, pero aún no logro lo que quiero, que es parar el audio al cambiar de fragment al hacer swipe

Answer (score 0):

Yo haría lo siguiente:

En tu **PagerAdapterFabula2** agregas:

```
private Pagina1fabula2Fragment tab1;
private Pagina2fabula2Fragment tab2;
private Fragmentpagina3fabula2 tab3;

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    if(position == 0) {
        fragment = new pagina1fabula2Fragment();
        if (this.tab1 != null) { return this.tab1; }
        this.tab1 = (Pagina1fabula2Fragment) fragment;
    }else if(position == 1) {
        fragment = new pagina2fabula2Fragment();
        if (this.tab2 != null) { return this.tab2; }
        this.tab2 = (Pagina1fabula2Fragment) fragment;
    }
    ... //Tus otros fragments
   return fragment;
}
```

puedes agregar un solo metodo o varios, para detener la reprodución;

```
public void stopAudioTab1() {
    if (this.tab1 == null) return; // Algo va mal con tu fragment
    this.tab1.stopAudio();
}
```

Para poder decirle al adapter que hagas las cosas solo haz las siguientes modificaciones:

```
tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        int position = tab.getPosition();
        if (position == 0) { adapter.stopAudioTab1(); }
        else if (position == 1) { adapter.stopAudioTab2(); }
        ... // tu logica 
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
    }

    @Override public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {}

    @Override public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {}
});
```

Espero te ayude.

Ojo: 
Con esta implementacion el estado de tus Fragments quedaran activos.